# VBA-runtime error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I have to populate an array storedata60 from a dynamic cell A1 of sheet6 for every thirty second. This array would reset to null after every 30min. Message box  would throw up message if the difference of max & minima is more than 7. I have 4 sub's for this activity. iam getting runtime error 9 subscript out of range. It is showing error at first line of my_procedure. Below the code:

```
Public RunWhen As Double    
Public Const cRunWhat = "my_Procedure"  
Dim I As Integer, n50max As Double, n50min As Double, Max_Min As Double, storedata60() As Double    

Option Explicit 

Sub StartTimer()    
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)    
    Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _    
      schedule:=True    
End Sub 


Sub StopTimer() 
   On Error Resume Next 
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _  
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False 
End Sub 


Sub my_Procedure()  
    storedata60(I) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").Value    
    n50max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(storedata60) 
    n50min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(storedata60) 
    Max_Min = n50max - n50min   
    If Max_Min >= 7 Then MsgBox Max_Min 
    I = I + 1   
    ReDim storedata60(I)    
    If I = 60 Then Call reset_zero  
    If I <> 60 Then Call StartTimer 
End Sub 


Sub reset_zero()    
    I = 0   
    Call StartTimer 
End Sub
```

Comment: @ J.schmidt, thanks. This resolved the issue. But the msg box is showing same data of A1 & not the difference of max-min. This message box appears in every 30 sec instead when max-min is more than 7. Would you please check this as well.

Comment: Your message box will appear if you `Max_Min` is equal to or more than **7**. If you only want it to appear when its more than **7**, change your `If` condition to: `If Max_Min > 7 Then MsgBox Max_Min` (**Notice**: I have removed **=** sign from the `If` condition)

Comment: @zac, the issue is not about => 7, the message box is throwing the same data that is entered in cell A1. But my requirement is to get message box only when difference of max and min of the data entered in A1  is more than or equal 7.

Comment: I only pointed that out because in your description you mentioned that you only want the message when your min and max is greater than 7. Not to linger on that point, I think your problem (from what I can see) is the `ReDim`. When you `ReDim` an array, it loses all previous values (so if you have 3 elements with values in your array and you `ReDim` the array to 4, and assign a value to the 4th element, you lose all values in first 3 elements). I suspect what you really want to do is `ReDim Preserve storedata60(I)`. This will retain your previous values

Comment: @zac, Thanks. Would check and revert.

Answer (score 0):

You have to size your array storedata60():

```
dim storedata60("size you need for this array") as double
```

EDIT:

or otherwise you'd have to redim your array before giving it a value:

```
Sub my_Procedure() 
ReDim storedata60(I) 
storedata60(I) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").Value    
'Following code
End Sub
```

Comment: I have redim it in the sub as it is a dynamic array. Please check.

Comment: But you use it in the first line and redim it later.